# Canvas offsetTop and offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML5 Canvas what is offsetTop and offsetLeft ?

I'm trying to get the X and Y of a a mouse click event. I know I can get that through:

```
mycanvas.onclick = function (evt) {
    var offX = evt.layerX - mycanvas.offsetLeft;
    var offY = evt.layerY - mycanvas.offsetTop;
}
```

but what is offsetLeft and offsetTop? and what is LayerX and LayerY ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The offsetLeft properties are specific to elements and is described in this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft) as:

> Returns the number of pixels that the upper left corner of the current
>   element is offset to the left within the offsetParent node.

LayerX specific to events and is described in this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.layerX) as:

> Returns the horizontal coordinate of the event relative to the current
>   layer.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN's document, the layerX and layerY are relative to the nearest positioned ancestor in the DOM tree.

I'm trying to fix this too...